# React Native - use sa state into a function

Tags: react-native, axios

I just want to use a state into an axios request (functional component), but doesn't work.

```
 const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

const updateTitle = title => {
    setTitle(title);
  };
  console.log(title); // comes from an input and work prefectly
```

I take the input with a button

```
<Button title="Search" onPress={() => searchBook(title)} />
```

Function

```
 const searchBook = ({title}) => {
    let key = '&key=MYKEY';

    googlebooks
      .request({
        method: 'get',
        url:
          'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' +
          title + // always undefined
          key,
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        setBookResults(response.data.items);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

I don't get any result, but `title` is always undefined. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your searchBook declaration is wrong. It is waiting for an object, but you use it with a non object variable.

```
const searchBook = title => {...}
```

Should work